# Gem install looks for misspelled gem name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I just installed the searchlogic gem, and when I run rake gems:install, I'm getting the following output:

```
gem install serachlogic
ERROR:  could not find gem serachlogic locally or in a repository
```

Not the misspelling of "**serachlogic**". I don't think that's an error I introduced, but I'm not sure where I can fix it.

Any ideas? Thanks....

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does it say in your environment.rb or Gemfile for this gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a typo in your Gemfile (if you use bundler) or `config/environment.rb`.

If all else fails, open up your editor and search all your project code for `serachlogic` to see where the problem is located.

Comment: Oye. Completely forgot the environment.rb file, but that's it. Clearly a newbie here -- thanks.